# Saving multiple hasMany through at once

Tags: cakephp, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have a many-to-many relation between 2 models `Invoice`and `Position` defined with the hasMany through method like described in the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model).

Now when i create a Invoice, i want to save multiple Positions to that Invoice in one `save()`-operation. Something like this:

```
$data = array(
  'Invoice' => array(
    // invoice stuff 
  ),
  'InvoicesPosition' => array(
    [0] => array(
      // additional meta information
      'Position' => array(
        // position stuff
        // ...
      ),
    ),
    [1] => array(
      // ...
      'Position' => array(
        // position stuff
        // ...
      ),
    ),
    // and so on
  ),
);  

$this->Invoice->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));
```

The result should be one new Invoice, with 2 Positions linked to it 
(That means 1 new record in the invoices table, 2 new records in the positions table and 2 new records in the join table).

Is it possible with Cake's built-in methods? Or do i have to overwrite the `saveAll()`-method for that model?

Comment: its a bit odd to fix the wrong code in the question, now it looks like it was correct in the first place, beter keep original question, and the approved answers will show other users with same issue what to change

Comment: Will keep that in mind for the next time. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'deep' => true` option in saveAll() method.

```
$this->Invoice->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));
```

Comment: Ah nice, thanks. I had to edit my `data` Array. See my code above.